# when exporting to the text file compare-object issue

Tags: powershell

I want to get an output like below.

My output now :

```
Name            Active PrimarySmtpAddress
----            ------ ------------------
DG_Group1       True   mail1@contoso.com
DG_Group2       False  mail2@contoso.com
DG_Group3       True   mail3@contoso.com
```

My desired output :

```
mail1@contoso.com
mail2@contoso.com
mail3@contoso.com
```

script :

```
$DistroLists  = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited
$MessageTrace = Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress $DistroLists.PrimarySmtpAddress -startdate (Get-Date).AddDays(-8) -EndDate (Get-Date)

$DistroLists |
    Foreach-Object {
       $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Active -Value (
           $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -in $MessageTrace.RecipientAddress
       ) -PassThru
   } | 
   Select-Object Name, Active, PrimarySmtpAddress | Where-Object Active -EQ "FALSE"
   Out-File C:\output.txt
```

Comment: You "want" one thing, but "desire" another? Which output format are you really interested in?

Comment: :)  sorry , it would be My desired output.

Comment: other it would be `My output now`  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` or `ForEach-Object -MemberName` to grab only the value of a specific property from one or more piped input objects:

```
... |Select-Object Name, Active, PrimarySmtpAddress | Where-Object Active -eq $false | ForEach-Object -MemberName PrimarySmtpAddress | Out-File...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip first two lines and split the line using space characters. Finally pick the last column as given below:

```
Get-Content C:\Projects\logtext.txt | Select-Object -Skip 2 | ForEach-Object { "$(($_ 
-split '\s+',3)[2])" }
```

```
mail1@contoso.com 
mail2@contoso.com
mail3@contoso.com
```